# Internet Settings in registry - Proxy auto login how to?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, proxy

I want to make auto login to system proxy.

I can set the proxy in registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Keys values:

```
ProxyEnable = 1
ProxyServer = IP:PORT
```

but I don't want the user of my application to enter login and password in his browser, I don't want him to click Login, I want to do this automatic.

I have tried to set ProxyServer key to:

```
ProxyServer = username:password@IP:PORT
```

But this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add `http://` before, so the value for `ProxyServer` should be:

```
http://username:password@proxy_server:port
```

It works! There is no proxy login box in my browser now :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [WebProxy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a32x5aw.aspx) for setting the credentials and proxy url

Answer (score 0):

You can also set **ProxyUser** and **ProxyPass** values to specify the username and password.